# Theorem 29.2 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

> ***Theorem 29.2.*** Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space. Then $X$ is locally compact if and only if given $x \in X$, and given a neighborhood $U$ of $x$,there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $\overline{V}$ is compact and $\overline{V} \subseteq U$.
>
> ***Proof:*** Clearly this new formulation implies local compactness; the set $C = \overline{V}$ is the desired compact set containing a neighborhood of $x$. To prove the converse, suppose $X$ is locally compact, let $x$ be a point of $X$ and let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x$. Take the one-point compactification $Y$ of $X$, and let $C$ be the set $Y - U$. Then $C$ is closed in $Y$, so that $C$ is a compact subspace of $Y$. Apply Lemma 26.4 to choose disjoint open sets $V$ and $W$ containing $x$ and $C$, respectively. Then the closure $\overline{V}$ of $V$ in $Y$ is compact, furthermore, $\overline{V}$ is disjoint from $C$, so that $\overline{V} \subset U$, as desired.

I don’t understand $\overline{V} \cap C=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $V\subset W^\complement$. Since $W$ is open, $W^\complement$ is a closed set. Therefore,$$\overline V\subset\overline{W^\complement}=W^\complement\subset C^\complement.$$So, $\overline V\cap C=\emptyset$.

Comment: Opss…. I didn’t see it. Thank you for the answer.